# How to pass the result from one task (on one host) to another task (on another host) inside an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I can't get this seemingly easy play to work:

```
---
- name: Get the filename
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - command: # find command that returns a filename
      register: filename 

- name: Use the filename on another hose
  hosts: host2
  tasks: 
    - command: #reuse the filename from above. How?
```

I tried vars, set_fact and hostvars - but I could not find a way to make this work

**How do I declare a global variable that can be set in one task, and then used in another?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two or three ways that I've been able to go about doing this and only one of them is a good idea.

1. use `delegate_facts: true` and `delegate_to: localhost` to set the fact on localhost instead of the host you're running on.  That, and only that, will survive an inventory reload if you do one of those inbetween.

```
 - name: Get the filename
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - command: # find command that returns a filename
      register: filename 

    - set_fact:
        global_filename: {{ filename }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: True

 - name: Use the filename on another host
   hosts: host2
   tasks: 
    - command: #reuse the {{ hostvars['localhost']['global_filename'] }} from above. How?
```

2. use add_host to add host to and set the variable on there, then you've got the host + the vars you wanted to use.

```
- name: Get the filename
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - command: # find command that returns a filename
      register: filename 

    - add_host:
        hostname: host2
        group: host_twos
        vars: 
        - host1_filename: {{ filename }} 

 - name: Use the filename on another host
   hosts: host_twos
   tasks: 
    - command: #reuse the {{ host1_filename }} from above. How?
```

3. write the facts to /tmp and reload with slurp or something. (I would not suggest this since it is liable to be insecure or get overwritten or plain old suck for a number of sundry reasons)

The better way, IMO to do this would simply be to delegate_to: host2 and run that task inside the first playbook.  That's the pattern I've consistently taken because every time I try to do 1,2 or 3, I wind up having big problems later on.

This looks like this:

```
- name: Get the filename
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - command: # find command that returns a filename
      register: filename 

    - command: #reuse the {{ filename }} from above. How?
      delegate_to: host2
```

Comment: I am confused. You list 3 ways, two of which you don't recommend, and in the end you recommend yet another solution How would this looks like in my play? I am not sure I understand delegate_to. I need the filename on host2 in order to extract the .tar file with that exavt name 

Comment: @tim I added some examples, I haven't tested them though, but I've implemented each of these patterns in the past and almost always settled on using delegate_to instead of trying to simulate global variables

Comment: Thank you very much 